# Threads not finishing when incremented by 1 more Java

Tags: java, multithreading

The code below works fine, however I want value to reach the end of the array, as at the moment it start from 1 then goes to the end of the array.

```
Booth[] boot = new Booth[numberOfBooths];


for (int j = 1; j < boot.length; j++) {
    boot[j] = new Booth(j, buff);
    boot[j].start();
}
for (int j =1 ; j < boot.length; j++) {
    try {
        boot[j].join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

I altered the code so the loops start from 0.. such:

```
for (int j = 0; j < boot.length; j++) {
    boot[j] = new Booth(j, buff);
    boot[j].start();
}
for (int j =0 ; j < boot.length; j++) {
    try {
        boot[j].join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
}
```

But after debugging as soon as it gets to the join the program stops. I read about Deadlock and maybe that was the reason for this, could there be a way around it, is there a general solution to this problem?

Edit:  Sorry I haven't been so clear. The code works either way, however when I run it a second time ( I have my program in a while loop ) it doesn't do the join

Comment: Looks fine to me. Maybe show use the definition of `Booth`?

Comment: What does your `Booth.run()` do?

Comment: You're going to have to show us what `Booth.start()` does and also what do you mean by "when I run it a second time it doesn't do the join"

Comment: So the whole thing is in a while loop, so while the user types in 'yes' the program restarts essentially.. It works absolutely beautifully on first run, but when it's the second run it stops on the join of the booth thread. @MrWiggles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds as if the thread pointed to by `boot[1]` completes, but the thread pointed to by `boot[0]` does not.

Therefore something about `new Booth(0,buff)` creates an object for which `run()` doesn't terminate.

Try unit testing `Booth` without using threads, and just run:

```
Booth b = new Booth(0,buff);  // initialise buff first, of course
b.run();
```

... and see whether this returns. If not, work out why, perhaps by stepping through it with a debugger.

The other thing to look out for is deadlock around the shared `buff` object. Unless there is some locking around `buff`, you can certainly expect issues. However that seems less likely if starting your index at 1 solves the problem.

If the whole thing works the first time around, but not on a second attempt, then you should consider the state of `buff`. Perhaps `new Booth(0,buff).run()` is non-terminating when supplied a certain state of `buff`.

---

Aside: It's cleaner to not do `class Booth extends Thread` but instead `class Booth implements Runnable`.

Then instead of `Booth.start()` use

```
Thread t = new Thread(booth);
t.start();
```

That way you're not polluting the `Booth` code with the knowledge that it's going to be a thread -- it's better encapsulation.

Comment: The buff is always kept the same, unit tested works fine. Something to do with the second time in the while loop, can't get my head around it

Comment: `buff` is read-only? (If so, it's not a good variable name -- it suggests a buffer). What is its type?

Comment: Buffer buff = new Buffer(10), its the amount of values it can hold before the officer must remove

Comment: Well it's not a `java.nio.Buffer` because that's abstract. So what is it? You didn't answer whether it's read-only.

Comment: Yeah sorry its read only     public Buffer(int i) {
        bufferSize = i;
        data = new Vote[bufferSize];
    }

Comment: Doesn't look very read-only to me. It very much looks as if the array of `Vote` in `data` is intended to be modified by `Booth` (otherwise what's the point of passing it to `Booth()`?) -- but we're guessing. As others have said, you need to show us (the relevant parts of) the `Booth` and `Buffer` code.

Comment: OK, so your problem is either to do with the state of the votes array for the second run through, or it's a race condition or deadlock issue around that array. It may be enough to reinitialise `buff` before the second run, but you should think carefully about it.

Comment: how do I find out which one it is?

Comment: Step through with a debugger.

Comment: I dont understand why It works perfectly for when I start the loop from 1 and not 0, literally makes no sense at all

Comment: Use a debugger to look at the state of the votes array before the second run through. Do some reasoning about that. Write a unit test taking a list of votes that looks the same.

Comment: okay so all I've found out, is that the values aren't being inserted into the buffer from the booth class, but the values have been assigned.